# bundle install doesn't work from capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano, bundler

I want to deploy my simple `rails 4.0` application via `capistrano 3.0`.

I use `bundler 1.3.5` so I add [capistrano-bundler](https://github.com/capistrano/bundler) gem to integrate bundler with capistrano.

I have pretty simple configuration (almost default):

```
set :bundle_gemfile, -> { release_path.join('Gemfile') }
set :bundle_dir, -> { shared_path.join('bundle') }
set :bundle_flags, ''
set :bundle_without, %w{test development}.join(' ')
set :bundle_binstubs, -> { shared_path.join('bin') }
set :bundle_roles, :all
```

When I run the `cap staging deploy --trace` it fails:

```
[50b524bc] Running /usr/bin/env bundle --gemfile /home/webmaster/www/api/releases/20131014144650/Gemfile --path /home/webmaster/www/api/shared/bundle  --binstubs /home/webmaster/www/api/shared/bin --without test development on 125.51.3.1
DEBUG [50b144bc] Command: cd /home/webmaster/www/api/releases/20131014144650 && /usr/bin/env bundle --gemfile /home/webmaster/www/api/releases/20131014144650/Gemfile --path /home/webmaster/www/api/shared/bundle  --binstubs /home/webmaster/www/api/shared/bin --without test development
cap aborted!
bundle stdout: Nothing written
bundle stderr: Nothing written
/home/omnomnom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sshkit-1.0.0/lib/sshkit/command.rb:94:in `exit_status='
/home/omnomnom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sshkit-1.0.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:125:in `block (4 levels) in _execute'
/home/omnomnom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:551:in `call'
/home/omnomnom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:551:in `do_request'
/home/omnomnom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:561:in `channel_request'
/home/omnomnom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:465:in `dispatch_incoming_packets'
/home/omnomnom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:221:in `preprocess'
/home/omnomnom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:205:in `process'
/home/omnomnom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `block in loop'
/home/omnomnom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/home/omnomnom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/home/omnomnom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:269:in `wait'
/home/omnomnom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sshkit-1.0.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:147:in `block (2 levels) in _execute'
/home/omnomnom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:514:in `call'
/home/omnomnom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:514:in `do_open_confirmation'
/home/omnomnom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:545:in `channel_open_confirmation'
/home/omnomnom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:465:in `dispatch_incoming_packets'
/home/omnomnom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:221:in `preprocess'
/home/omnomnom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:205:in `process'
/home/omnomnom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `block in loop'
/home/omnomnom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/home/omnomnom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/home/omnomnom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sshkit-1.0.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:149:in `block in _execute'
/home/omnomnom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sshkit-1.0.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:106:in `tap'
/home/omnomnom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sshkit-1.0.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:106:in `_execute'
/home/omnomnom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sshkit-1.0.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `execute'
/home/omnomnom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-bundler-1.0.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/bundler.cap:20:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/omnomnom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sshkit-1.0.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:81:in `within'
/home/omnomnom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-bundler-1.0.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/bundler.cap:19:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/omnomnom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sshkit-1.0.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:42:in `instance_exec'
/home/omnomnom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sshkit-1.0.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:42:in `run'
/home/omnomnom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sshkit-1.0.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => deploy:updated => bundler:install
```

But if I copy this command and run though ssh all works fine (all gems installed successfully) How I can fix/debug it?

Comment: Rubygems has problems today. Try again later...

Comment: @spickermann but gems download works well if I run this command through ssh...

Comment: Post your capfile and deploy.rb, there's probably some configuration issue.  Also, make sure that your deploy user has write permissions to the gem's directory

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Just ran into the same issue. What worked for me was this:

1) Installing the `capistrano-rvm` gem and adding

```
require 'capistrano/rvm'
```

to the `Capfile`.

2) Adding my deployment user to the `rvm` group on the server:

```
# usermod deploy -a -G rvm
```

3) Creating two directories in my deployment user's home folder: `.rvm` and `.rvm/bin`

4) Adding this line to my `deploy.rb` file:

```
set :default_env, { rvm_bin_path: '~/.rvm/bin' }
```

Phew! That took a few hours.

Comment: Did you found the root of the problem?

Comment: Not really (was pressed for time and had to get it running pronto). I suspect it has something to do with rvm settings not getting loaded when Capistrano logs in (as opposed to a regular shell login, see [here](http://www.capistranorb.com/documentation/faq/why-does-something-work-in-my-ssh-session-but-not-in-capistrano/)). I started looking into it but then decided to take the path with rvm wrappers and it worked.

Comment: it worked for me, only one correction : I had to change to change require 'capistrano/rvm' to require 'rvm/capistrano' and everything worked fine

Comment: Ahh! I was under the impression default_environment was removed! It's only been renamed. Nice! Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

The error sounds like it can't find `bundle` in your `PATH`. It's possible that when you SSH in manually, it's running something in your `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` that adds it to your path.

Find the path to `bundle` by logging in and running `which bundle`. Then, try to find how that path is added to your `PATH` environment variable. If there's something in your `~/.bash_profile, try moving it to`~/.bashrc` instead.

You can also try [Command Mapping](http://www.capistranorb.com/2013/06/01/release-announcement.html#toc_12) to specify an exact path.

There are some more troubleshooting tips at http://www.capistranorb.com/documentation/faq/why-does-something-work-in-my-ssh-session-but-not-in-capistrano/

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution and working on all Capistrano 3 versions:

```
gem 'rvm1-capistrano3', require: false
```

In Capfile add

```
require 'rvm1/capistrano3'
```

https://github.com/rvm/rvm1-capistrano3

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I changed config/deploy.rb's `set :log_level, :info` to `set :log_level, :debug`, which showed me "Can not find GEMFILE." This suggested that `bundle` was running with the wrong working directory, so I changed

```
before "deploy:assets:precompile", "deploy:bundle_install"
desc "Bundle install for RVMs sake"
task :bundle_install do
  on roles(:app) do
    execute "/u0/jrepenni/.rvm/bin/rvm 2.1.0@akiary do /u0/jrepenni/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/bin/bundle install"
  end
end
```

to

```
before "deploy:assets:precompile", "deploy:bundle_install"
desc "Bundle install for RVMs sake"
task :bundle_install do
  on roles(:app) do
    execute "cd #{release_path} && /u0/jrepenni/.rvm/bin/rvm 2.1.0@akiary do /u0/jrepenni/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/bin/bundle install"
  end
end
```

(note the added "cd")

Answer (score 1):

I had:

```
set :bundle_flags, '--system --quiet'
```

Changed to:

```
set :bundle_flags, '--deployment --quiet'
```

This resolved a problem.

Answer (score 0):

**This works in capistrano 3:**

```
  task :bundle_list do
    on roles(:app) do
      within release_path do
        with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
          execute :bundle, "list"
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Use this for rake task :

```
execute :rake, 'some_rake_task'
```

Answer (score 0):

in your config/deploy/production.rb file put

```
set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.0.0-p247'
```

see https://github.com/capistrano/rvm

Answer (score 0):

```
gem install bundler
```

is what I needed to run on my deploy user in order for Capistrano's:

```
/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm 2.4.0 do bundle install --path /var/www/hivebench-api/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet
```

to pass!

Answer (score 0):

I got `cannot execute 'bundle'` issues after upgrading ruby (using rbenv).  For some reason my deployment setup seems to be relying upon the default rbenv version set on the server.  So the fix for me was:

`rbenv global 2.7.4`

Answer (score -1):

To debug it try to remove the `--quiet` flag:

`set :bundle_flags, '--deployment'`

Are you using rbenv, rvm or something similar? It might be possible that when `bundle` is running the Ruby version is not set yet. By removing the `--quite` flag you might get some debugging information.

Comment: As you can see, there is no ```--quiet``` flag in the command because I have already removed it. I use rvm how I can debug if the ruby have been already setted?