# Capistrano v3 could not find a Bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, bundler

I have a problem in deploying my App with Capistrano v3. When I run '$ cap production deploy' I see an error...

```
 INFO [825ad68d] Running /usr/bin/env bundle --gemfile /home/username/www/myapp/releases/20131026181031/Gemfile --path /home/username/www/myapp/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --binstubs /home/username/www/myapp/shared/bin --without development test on myhostname.com
DEBUG [825ad68d] Command: cd /home/username/www/myapp/releases/20131026181031 && ( RAILS_ENV=production /usr/bin/env bundle --gemfile /home/username/www/myapp/releases/20131026181031/Gemfile --path /home/username/www/myapp/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --binstubs /home/username/www/myapp/shared/bin --without development test )
DEBUG [825ad68d]    /usr/bin/env: 
DEBUG [825ad68d]    bundle
DEBUG [825ad68d]    : No such file or directory
```

But when I run the last command...

```
cd /home/username/www/myapp/releases/20131026181031 && ( RAILS_ENV=production /usr/bin/env bundle --gemfile /home/username/www/myapp/releases/20131026181031/Gemfile --path /home/username/www/myapp/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --binstubs /home/username/www/myapp/shared/bin --without development test )
```

... via ssh on my server I don't see any errors.

Here is my server's environment:

- Ubuntu 13.04
- rvm 1.23.5
- rubygems 1.8.25
- Bundler 1.3.5
- ruby 1.9.3p448
- capistrano (3.0.0)
- capistrano-bundler (1.0.0)
- capistrano-rails (1.0.0)

**Here is a piece of my Gemfile which includes capistrano's gems**

```
...
group :development do
  ...
  # Deploy with Capistrano
  gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.0.0'
  gem 'capistrano-rails'
  gem 'capistrano-bundler'
end
...
```

Please see below capistrano's configuration:

**Capfile**

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'

Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.cap').each { |r| import r }
```

**config/deploy.rb**

```
set :application, 'myapp'
set :repo_url, "/home/username/repository/#{fetch(:application)}.git"
set :deploy_to, "/home/usename/www/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :scm, :git
set :branch, "master"
set :format, :pretty
set :use_sudo, false

set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

set :keep_releases, 5

SSHKit.config.command_map[:rake]  = "bundle exec rake"
SSHKit.config.command_map[:rails] = "bundle exec rails"

namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      # Your restart mechanism here, for example:
      # execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
      # within release_path do
      #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
      # end
    end
  end

  after :finishing, 'deploy:cleanup'
end
```

**config/deploy/production.rb**

```
set :stage, :production

set :bundle_gemfile, -> { release_path.join('Gemfile') }
set :bundle_dir, -> { shared_path.join('bundle') }
set :bundle_flags, '--deployment --quiet'
set :bundle_without, %w{development test}.join(' ')
set :bundle_binstubs, -> { shared_path.join('bin') }
set :bundle_roles, :all

role :app, %w{myhostname.com}
role :web, %w{myhostname.com}
role :db,  %w{myhostname.com}

server 'myhostname.com', user: 'username', roles: %w{web app}, my_property: :my_value

fetch(:default_env).merge!(rails_env: :production)
```

Please help me.

**SOLVED**

I've solved my problem by following steps:

Add capistrano-rvm into **Gemfile** and do

```
...
group :development do
  ...
  gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.0.0'
  gem 'capistrano-rails'
  gem 'capistrano-bundler'
  gem 'capistrano-rvm'
end
...
```

Add this line into Capfile

```
require 'capistrano/rvm'
```

Add these lines into the **deploy.rb** file.

```
set :rvm_ruby_version, '1.9.3-p448'
set :default_env, { rvm_bin_path: '~/.rvm/bin' }
SSHKit.config.command_map[:rake] = "#{fetch(:default_env)[:rvm_bin_path]}/rvm ruby-#{fetch(:rvm_ruby_version)} do bundle exec rake"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [bundle install doesn't work from capistrano](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363077/bundle-install-doesnt-work-from-capistrano)

Comment: after adding gem `capistrano-rvm` in Gemfile, run bundle, then add require `capistrano/rvm` in `Capfile`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that you had to add `capistrano-rvm`. It will take care about your **ruby** and **bundler** paths.

[bundle install doesn't work from capistrano](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363077/bundle-install-doesnt-work-from-capistrano)

Comment: I added capistrano-rvm and it solved the problem but another problem appeared. I think this one and previous one are similar (see below):

`DEBUG [3686e995] Command: cd /home/username/www/myapp/releases/20131027130646 && ( RVM_BIN_PATH=~/.rvm/bin RAILS_ENV= ~/.rvm/bin/rvm ruby-1.9.3-p448 do rake assets:precompile )
DEBUG [3686e995]  /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in block in materialize'
DEBUG [3686e995] : 
DEBUG [3686e995] Could not find i18n-0.6.1 in any of the sources
DEBUG [3686e995] (
DEBUG [3686e995]  Bundler::GemNotFound`

Comment: @ekondr As you can see, you haven't specified ```RAILS_ENV``` try to add ```set :rails_env, "production"``` instead of ```fetch(:default_env).merge!(rails_env: :production)```

Comment: I've added `set :rails_env, "production"` instead of `fetch(:default_env).merge!(rails_env: :production)` but nothing changed.

Comment: I've fixed my problem. I've added these lines into the deploy.rb file.

`set :rvm_ruby_version, '1.9.3-p448'`  
`set :default_env, { rvm_bin_path: '~/.rvm/bin' }`  
`SSHKit.config.command_map[:rake]  = "#{fetch(:default_env)[:rvm_bin_path]}/rvm ruby-#{fetch(:rvm_ruby_version)} do bundle exec rake"`

Comment: @ekondr so all works as expected now? If migrations and assets compilation works well?

Answer (score 0):

> ... via ssh on my server I don't see any errors.

The problem you are seeing is probably due to missing rbenv, chruby, or rvm. This is a really common one and it's documented here how to resolve, verify and/or work around (whichever works for your case) here:

- http://www.capistranorb.com/documentation/faq/why-does-something-work-in-my-ssh-session-but-not-in-capistrano/

Comment: I don't see any instructions on that link for how to resolve.  Good explanation of the problem though.

Answer (score 0):

If you use system rvm (path = /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm), set capistrano-bundler as below

```
set :rvm_type, :system
set :rvm_ruby_version, 'ruby-<version>@<gemset>'
```