# Capistrano does not find bundler

Tags: deployment, capistrano, bundler

When I try to deploy im getting a:

```
bash: /srv/books/current/bin/bundle: No such file or directory
```

When I login on the deploy server doing 'which bundler' results is:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@books/bin/bundle
```

Problem when I use the ssh that capistrano uses to deploy and do which then:

```
ssh root@server 'which bundler'
```

It throws

```
which: no bundler in (/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/lib/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [bundle install doesn't work from capistrano](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363077/bundle-install-doesnt-work-from-capistrano)

Answer (score 2):

For more information on why some things in Capistrano don’t work, when they work perfectly in an SSH session, it might be best to read through http://www.capistranorb.com/documentation/faq/why-does-something-work-in-my-ssh-session-but-not-in-capistrano/ and see if you can reproduce the problem after reading through that.

You don't mention which version of Capistrano you are using, but for both 2.x and 3.x there are decent (3rd party and first party) integrations for RVM available)